# Highcharts show tooltip on load with table datasource?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts, and getting it's data from a table. What I want to do, is "activate" a tooltip when the chart is rendered so it shows a default tooltip on page load.

I've read in another question that this could be done with something like `chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[1].points[2]);`
As demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/t9hf1j46/

However my scenario is rather different since I am not getting my data from a *"series"*, but from a table.

I have cooked down a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/90uafg7a/2/
And when I try to do something like `chart.tooltip.refresh(dataSeries.series[0].data[1]);` an error is thrown in my console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tooltipOptions' of undefined`.

I hope someone can help me out here.. :-)

Comment: Doh.. You are the man. Submit an answer if you want :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `chart.series[0].data[index]`, not `dataSeries` - working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/90uafg7a/3